# UIImagePicker Camera view not fullscreen Ipad2

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

The problem looks like it centers somehow around the popover event.  Ex. I click Camera.. it launches the camera modally up to the absolute top of the screen.. If I click cancel and repeat.. everything looks perfect.  Now If I choose to view the popover camera Roll.. the next time Camera is launched it about 20px from the top of the screen also and button nav bar is only half viewable.  (keep in mind standard screen has the from the standard topbar but the modal camera takes up the full absolute screen 1024x768).

my code:

```
- (IBAction) getPhoto: (id)sender
{
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];    
    }
}

- (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender
{
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    } 
    else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        popoverController.delegate = self;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    UIImage *savedimage = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = savedimage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (savedimage, self, nil, nil);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you present the UIImagePickerController in the popover, the popover is holding on to the view and causing you some issues. Trying releasing the view from the popover by either destroying the popover (and thus its subviews) or setting the popover content to nil. 
Ex.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.popoverController setContentViewController:nil]; 
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    UIImage *savedimage = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = savedimage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (savedimage, self, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: nope..  I'm assuming it should be something in the useCameraRoll popover.  If I avoid that popover everything is absolutely fine.  If that popover is used though.. it caused the camera to never modally go to the absolute top of the screen.

Comment: I think when the imagepicker's view is created it offsets it to fit in the popover with the appropriate border. Maybe try recreating the imagepicker or resetting its frame